# Dynamically change connection string in a controller with Asp.Net Core with Entity Framework and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 web application with Entity Framework and Dependency Injection and I would like to change the connection string (then the database) at run time once login is successful (in "HomeController"). My actual situation is:

```
Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
         ...
          // This is made for the login
          services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContextLogin>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AdminConnection")));

            // This for the database that HAVE to be dynamic
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`
         ...

            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWorkLogin, UnitOfWorkLogin>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}
```

This my HomeController:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();

            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claims = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (claims != null)
            { 
                user = _unitOfWorkLogin.ApplicationUser.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == claims.Value);
            }

            if (user.UserName != null)
            {
                //Here I want to set my new connection string and connecting to the database relating to the user.
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

How can achieve this? I'm quite new so I need clear explenation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to change the connection string? Are you using different databases for different users?

Comment: @IanKemp, yes I'm using different databases for different users, and I have the issue that "ApplicationDbContext" if it gets injected by DI, it has a fixed database connection so I am not able to change it. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: looks like we can use a multitenant solution for this kind of issue, of course that's just a solution beside many others.

Comment: @Hopeless, thank you, I was already reading and then thinking about multitenant solution but honestly I have not clear knoweledge about that, any further tips?

Comment: @MaurizioOrlandi the purpose of multitenant is to use one site for different sets/groups of users/customers who require different behaviors/settings which come from our app configurations ... with the most effected by the Dependency Injection. I think it's some kind of fairly advanced feature and a bit challenging to setup. Actually I've never done any project requiring multitenant feature :) so I'm really not helpful following that way. All I have now is some knowledge about it. You can go for a simpler approach if having not much time to solve this.

Comment: @Hopeless I have not much time but I'm already a lot in this direction so I will try to work on it. Thanks.

Comment: ok, good luck, I'm pretty sure it's feasible and not too hard to setup, you may have to use a custom DI container, such as `autofac`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented below, which works with appsettings.json file.

**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionSettings": [
{
  "Organization": "abc",
  "ConnectionString": ""
},
{
  "Organization": "xyz",
  "ConnectionString": ""
}
]
```

**AppSettings.cs**

```
public class AppSettings : IAppSettings
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private List<ConnectionSetting> _connectionSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the organization of the current user.
    /// </summary>
    public string CurrentOrganization { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User settings of the current user from appsettings.json.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectionSetting CurrentOrganizationSettings
    {
        get
        {
            var connectionSetting = _connectionSettings?.Where(us => us.Organization.Equals(CurrentOrganization, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (connectionSetting == null)
                return _connectionSettings.FirstOrDefault();
            else
                return connectionSetting;
        }
    }
 }
```

**startup.cs**

```
 public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IAppContext, Services.AppContext>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
        services.AddScoped<IConnectionStringService, Services.ConnectionStringService>();
    }
```

**ConnectionStringService.cs**

```
public class ConnectionStringService : IConnectionStringService
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    IAppContext _appContext;
    public ConnectionStringService(IAppContext appContext)
    {
        _appContext = appContext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get connection string of current user from appsettings.json.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Connection string of the current user</returns>
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return _appContext.AppSettings.CurrentOrganizationSettings.ConnectionString;
    }
  }
```

**AppContext.cs**

```
public class AppContext : IAppContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Application settings stored in appsettings.json.
    /// </summary>
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public AppContext(IAppSettings appSettings, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        AppSettings = appSettings;
        string organization = null;
        var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            organization = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("organization")?.Value;
        }
        else if (request != null && request.Path.Value.Contains("login"))
        {
            try
            {
                var loginModel = request.ReadFormAsync().Result;
                loginModel.TryGetValue("organization", out StringValues organizationValues);
                organization = organizationValues;                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot retrieve organization from the http request. " +
                    "Make sure login request contains organization as application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ex);
            }
        }
        AppSettings.CurrentOrganization = organization;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look to understand if it fits with what I need.